# How do I configure a negative clamper in LTspice?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, ltspice, pulse

I am trying to make a negative clamper in LTspice. The pulse source goes from 10V to -10V harmonically. My aim is to lower it's voltage by 7.3V, so it will have a pulse graph going from 2.7 to -17.3V, but I don't know how to configure the circuit for that.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *My aim is to lower it's Voltage by 7.3V, so it will have a pulse graph
> going from 2.7 to -17.3V. But I don't know how to configure the
> circuit for that*

You need D2 to be equivalent to an ideal diode in series with a voltage source of 2.7 volts: -

[image]

This prevents the voltage on the anode of D2 rising any higher than +2.7 volts. If the only model of diode you have has a forward volt drop that isn't zero (ideal) you will have to play around the the 2.7 volt source by lowering it maybe 0.5 volts. Experiment!!!

Comment: I put a 2.7V voltage source as you suggested and the graph looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/MzSuNb2.png
It spikes at the beginning and it's lower parts doesn't look horizontal. How can this be fixed?

Comment: @Pascal Try making R2 something like 10 Mohm and try adding a 100 ohm in series with the capacitor. However, it seems your question is actually answered so, if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.